# Fully cover the container using a proportionally scaled image

Tags: css

I want to scale an image with CSS following these rules:

```
if (containerWidth/containerHeight >=imgWidth/imgHeight) --> img { width: 100% }
if (containerWidth/containerHeight < imgWidth/imgHeight) --> img { height: 100% }
```

The idea is to fully cover the container using a proportionally scaled image using CSS (without javascript).

Desired result: http://jsfiddle.net/pu76s/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a background image with the CSS3 attribute `background-size: cover`

http://jsfiddle.net/UUhVf/

You can adjust the positioning with the `background-position` attribute

Comment: Thanks but I'm asking to scale an image (thumbnails), not setting a background.

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle. It does exactly what you wanted. If you want to create an actual thumbnail I'd recommend to use imagemagick

Comment: Alright - I don't see the problem. Instead of using `<div><img src="theImage.png"/></div>` you will be using `<div style="background-image: url('theImage.png')" />`

Comment: My CSP doesn't allows inline styles.

Comment: Well, here are a few options then: 1) Generate a dynamic CSS file and set the background-image there 2) Use JavaScript to calculate width and height 3) Generate thumbnails in the right size in the first place

Comment: So it's impossible to get the desired result with images and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky thing to solve without JS, as CSS has no way of knowing an image's aspect ratio.

If you are able to detect the AR from your back-end and set a class, I'd do something like:

```
img.portrait {
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

img.landscape {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```